# Why chrome(chromium) use infinite linear animation lead to cpu always high usage on macos

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, animation

I found chrome(chromium) use infinite linear css animation will lead to cpu always high usage on macos, but not in Safari or other not chromium browser. In chrome has a GPU process, and this process has been running at high CPU usage. I found a soluation(vscode soluation), replace `linear` with `steps(30)`, throttle fps to 30.

My question is why linear timing function so lag on macos Chrome but not on Windows.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/96096/files

Comment: This is the same on Linux too :-(
This is known issue since... 2015: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491422